# expo-ads-admob not updating as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, admob, expo, expo-ads-admob

As I'm sure many are aware, admob needed an update to use a newer SDK (7.64+) and this message appears on your admob account if you have apps using an SDK below that version:

> Some of your iOS apps require a GMA SDK update To keep ads serving normally and minimize a loss in ad revenue, implement the GMA SDK 7.64.0 (or later) for your iOS apps. And configure the SKAdNetwork in your apps with Google's network ID.

Expo had a PR [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/12125) that was merged 6 days ago. This should have updated the GMA SDK to 7.69.0. However, when I ran `expo upgrade` it states that it updated expo-ads-admob,

> ✅ The following packages were updated:
> expo-ads-admob, expo-av, expo-keep-awake, expo-updates, react-native, react, react-dom, @babel/core, react-native-web, babel-preset-expo, expo

but no changes actually take effect. And if I have the newer version (10.0.0) that I manually installed as stated below, it downgrades it to 8.4.0.

When that wasn't working, I then went and manually updated expo-ads-admob to 10.0.0 via npm (also tried yarn) and it looked like the node package was actually updated (checking the CHANGELOG and it has info about 10.0.0).

Still when I build my app with `expo build:ios`, run the new app, and check my GMA SDK version on admob it is still using `7.55.1`.

I have also tried completely removing expo-ads-admob and reinstalling, but the same issue occurs.

Any ideas as to why this is occurring? Is there some other method I should be using to upgrade to the latest commit on expo's master branch?

Appreciate all the assistance in advance and let me know if there is any additional info I can provide.

**Additional Info:**

1. SDK Version: 40.0.0
2. Platform: iOS
3. Workflow: Managed

EDIT: Received answer from Expo member, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use updated packages if using the `managed` workflow, it must be `bare` workflow in order to update module versions manually. Therefore, this admob update won't take place for `managed` workflows until expo SDK 41 is released.

See expo forum [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-ads-admob-not-updating-as-expected/49979) for more.